# Java javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch

Tags: java, encryption

Can someone help on why I am getting "javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch" error? Not sure, what I am missing.
Below is the decryption util code.  EncryptedData includes initVector as well.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.security.SecureRandom

class GCMEncryptionUtil {
    static final String AES = "AES"
    static final String AES_GCM_NO_PADDING = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"

    static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128
    static final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12

    private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String encryptedDataWithIV = args[0]
        SecretKey key = generateSecretFromSymmetricKey("thisismysecretkey")
        decrypt(encryptedDataWithIV, key)
    }

    static String decrypt(String encryptedData, SecretKey secret) throws Exception {
        byte[] encryptedDataInBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData)
        ByteBuffer cipherTextBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedDataInBytes)

        // Get IV from cipherText
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH_BYTE]
        cipherTextBuffer.get(iv)

        // Remove IV from cipherText which is actual payload to be decrypted
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipherTextBuffer.remaining()]
        cipherTextBuffer.get(cipherText)

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_NO_PADDING)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv))
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText)
        return new String(plainText, UTF_8)
    }

    static SecretKey generateSecretFromSymmetricKey(String key) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key)
        new SecretKeySpec(bytes, 0, bytes.length, AES)
    }
}
```

Comment: It means either the key is wrong or the ciphertext was corrupted.

Comment: In "generateSecretFromSymmetricKey" you are generating a secret key with byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key) - I don't believe that "thisismysecretkey" is a valid Base64-string. For more help please share the encryption part as well to see what is in the encryptedString and in what order, thanks.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Or the order or size of the IV, ciphertext and tag is incorrect, or course.